# show/hide function using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a toogle button something like that when I click that menu-wrapper should broaden its width and sidebar should hide.

This is the normal css

```
#my-wrapper {
Width:500px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
width:200px;
}
```

So when I click that button the CSS

```
#my-wrapper {
Width:700px;

}

#sidebar-wrapper {
width:200px;
display:none;
}
```

Comment: There are a lot of examples on the internet regarding this.. Please search for it.. it's an easy task.. don't expect us to do your work..

Comment: I am not able to do it with Jquery or JS actually I am not knowing how to implement it I search Stackoverflow about this I got some answers but they didn't help that's why it forced me to create this topic

Comment: Dw, i didnt downvote you.. but here's the answer.. $('#menu-wrapper').click(function(){ $('#sidebar-wrapper').hide(); });

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to increase the width of the wrapper and hiding sidebar

**jQuery :**

```
$('#menu-wrapper').click(function(){
    $("#my-wrapper").toggleClass('active');
    $('#sidebar-wrapper').toggleClass('hide'); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
#my-wrapper.active {
    width: 700px;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by wrapping both your `DIV`s inside a parent div, and toggle a `hidden` class on button click. Also, you can do the CSS you want inside the `hidden` class.

HTML:

```
<a id="toggle" href="#">Toggle</a>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="my-wrapper"></div>
    <div id="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#my-wrapper {
    width: 500px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 200px;
}

#wrapper.hidden #my-wrapper {
    width: 700px;
}

#wrapper.hidden #sidebar-wrapper {
    display: none;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$("#toggle").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $("#wrapper").toggleClass("hidden");
});
```

Live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/0wmsmca6/